# create a MenuItem via Dashboard, as root that does not act like a link

Tags: orchardcms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`. How can I create a `MenuItem` via `Dashboard`, as root that does not act like a link and just show the `subMenuItems`.
(In dashboard selecting a content item is mandatory for a MenuItem)

So is this possible to Achieve this some how via dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orchard has `Custom Link` menu item type, which let you add any custom URL (internal or external) for your menu, you can use it and set `Url` property to `#`.